# Authentication to a Azure AD (auth 2.0) WebAPI from WPF-desktop app on .NET Core

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We are creating a desktop application using WPF on .NET Core 3.1.

Im trying to connect to a web api with Azure AD Authenticaton, by following for example [this guide](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API). However, the sample project (which works ok) is written in WPF on .NET Framework.

There is a client part and a server (web api)-part. Since the client is a desktop application you should register api-part with (Azure-->AD--> app registrations... ) with a reply url of "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"

I initialize my PublicClientApplicationBuilder with

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(ClientIdPorterApplication)
        .WithAuthority(authority) 
        .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
        .Build();
```

and when running app.AcquireTokenInteractive(...) get the error message:

> Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient was
>   found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during
>   app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication
>   object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details

(this address works well to use in the example, but again, its written on .NET FW)

so, just for fun I changed the replyUrl (both in initialization above and Azure Portal App registration) to "http://localhost:1234". The user gets the "choose account"-dialog in a web browser and after selecting account myname@mycompany.com the message below is displayed:

> Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free
>   to close this browser tab.

Yeay!, right?...not quite. In the code I still get the exception with with error message:

> {"A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error
>   message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration
>   in the application registration portal. See
>   https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original
>   exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following
>   parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID:
>   7b0f6384-64eb-422c-a996-cadaa52f1f00\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   0c579b5b-e706-4625-96da-fbf03e5a21f9\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-23
>   12:14:59Z"}

Any clues? I read somewhere in a googling frenzy that this is not possible on a WPF on .net core-scenario. Im sure the must be a solution

**EDIT:**
In my my final browser window (with the message "Authentication complete...", the url in the url-window has a qstring param code=
[image]

Comment: Can you share all the reply urls (and its platform) that you have configured in AAD for this app?

Comment: This is a desktop app so the only reply urls Iv used are in my original question. Are you referring to how they look in the manifest-file? I dont see how I can respond to any callbacks on a desktop app. Just for fun I also spun up a TcpListener on than port on startup but got a "file is already in use"-error

Comment: I believe your own answer is correct. I just wanted to make sure that you set the platform as desktop and not Web. Even though your reply url is http, the platform must be desktop in your case

Answer (score 2):

I can only accept my own answer tomorrow, if I forget, this is the answer

This is what worked for me:
The just for fun-settings is the way to go:

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientIdPorterApplication)                                              
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:1234")
            .Build();
```

(could be any port, but it must be not used by any other). 
...

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes) 
                                        .WithAuthority(authority) 
                                        .ExecuteAsync()
                                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

The msal will listen to this port and get the token from the browser in a magical way

In azure there are two app registration, client(my desktop app) and server (web api).

- Server: Just follow the guide in original question
- Client (plus guide):
  For the (Azure Portal->AAD-->App reg-page->Authentication:

  - "Treat application as a public client." should be "Yes"
  - [Add a platform] ->Mobile and desktop, add your reply url here (mine is 
    http://localhost:1234 above)